# Network profile lost on almost all sites

Tags: support

I have a very strange problem here.

If I sign in with Google on drupal.stackexchange.com, I still see my reputation and badges.

However, all other sites I was active on force me to create a new account and show me my network profile user name. After that, my user profile is blank and not linked with my questions, answers and comments, so all my reputation and badges are lost suddenly. Are you serious?

Sites I am active on are

- askubuntu
- server fault
- stackoverflow

to name just a few.

Can anyone explain why my profiles have suddenly disappeared?

Comment: Can you link to one of your still-active accounts?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/11796/josh

Comment: That account is linked with your account here on Meta; what accounts are yours  but are *not* linked to your Drupal account? Specifically, what is your Server Fault account, for example? You can [edit] your question to add more information.

Answer (score 4):

You had a few different open Ids (using a couple of different email addresses) used on different accounts across the network.

Given that some were already linked, I merged the remaining accounts based on the matching email addresses, so all should be well now.